# Wired speaker vs Wired headphones

Tags: android, android-audiomanager

I am trying to implement recording in a background audio. So, when a user uses wired headphones I need to record + overlay the background audio. And when a user uses wired speaker I don't need to overlay background audio.

So, while trying to detect between wired speaker (external speaker) and earphones (headset), I am getting the same constant values from both the output devices while using the following code which is making it even harder

```
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
AudioDeviceInfo[] audioDevices = audioManager.getDevices(AudioManager.GET_DEVICES_OUTPUTS);
for (AudioDeviceInfo deviceInfo : audioDevices){
    deviceInfo.getType(); 
}
}
```

Getting values `TYPE_BUILTIN_EARPIECE,TYPE_BUILTIN_SPEAKER,TYPE_WIRED_HEADPHONES,TYPE_TELEPHONY.`

Can someone point me to the right direction here ?

Comment: I doubt that an Android device can necessarily distinguish between wired speakers (where the speakers happen to be sitting on a desk) and wired speakers (where the speakers happen to be clamped to a user's ears). That might be possible with USB-C devices, but not with classic 2.5mm headphone jacks.

Comment: I updated the actual use case on my question. May be you can suggest what else I could do.

Comment: Perhaps you could let the user control whether you overlay background audio or not, using a switch or checkbox.